# Glossy render works in 2.8, but not in 3.2.2

Tags: cycles-render-engine

A year or two ago I made a setup where I can make whatever scene I want, which will be rendered like an environment map onto a texture, by rendering the gloss of a mesh.
*The reason I did it this way was because I wanted to decide myself what orientation the render result has, it's easier for me.*

This still works perfectly fine in 2.8. No problemo, everithing's awesome.
[image: Works in 2.8]

However, opening the exact same blend file in 3.2.2 and rendering it gives me a black render.
[image: No worky in 3.2.2]

I do know you can render an environment texture onto a model, as described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92535/how-to-bake-glossy-materials)
, but that is just a texture. I want the entire scene with all objects and lights and stuff.

Is there anything I am missing, or is this just straight up impossible now?

Comment: I understand it's the same file, but could you make sure the sphere is correctly unwrapped ?

Comment: Are you implying that all of a sudden the uvmap is changed just by opening it in another version of blender? The UVmap is correct. Nothing is outside the image boundary.

Comment: hehe no, I'm explicitely trying to find out what might have gone wrong in your file :)